# In GAE, how do I set the timeout of libraries not using urlfetch?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've set the default deadline to 60 by `urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)`, but when fetching a url, after exactly 10 seconds, it still raises `DeadlineExceededError`.

The call is done by an API wrapper, so it's not using `urlfetch` but `httplib2`. But I've already did modifications to the wrapper's timeout as well.

EDIT: some code

```
class ContextioHandler(BaseAPIHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, response):
        urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)
        self.cio = contextIO2.ContextIO(config.CONTEXTIO_API_KEY,
                                        config.CONTEXTIO_API_SECRET,
                                        timeout=60)
        self.initialize(request, response)

    def get(self):
        account = self.cio.get_accounts(email='foo@bar.com')
        account = account[0]
        account.get_message('abc123')
```

context.io wrapper library constructor

```
class ContextIO(object):
    url_base = "https://api.context.io"

    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, timeout=None):
        self.consumer = Consumer(key=consumer_key, secret=consumer_secret)
        self.client = Client(self.consumer, timeout=timeout)
        self.client.set_signature_method(sha1())
        self.base_uri = '2.0'
```

AppEngine logs (trimmed):

```
...
D 2013-06-05 05:02:09.321 GET https://api.context.io/2.0/accounts?email=foo%40bar.com
D 2013-06-05 05:02:10.091 GET https://api.context.io/2.0/accounts/xyz123/messages/abc123
E 2013-06-05 05:02:19.992 Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://api.context.io/2.0/accounts/xyz123/messages/abc123
...
D 2013-06-05 04:58:15.763 GET https://api.context.io/2.0/accounts?email=foo%40bar.com
D 2013-06-05 04:58:15.820 GET https://api.context.io/2.0/accounts/xyz123/messages/abc123
E 2013-06-05 04:58:25.715 Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://api.context.io/2.0/accounts/xyz123/messages/abc123
...
```

It's always ~10 seconds.

Comment: Have you tested with urlfetch ?

Comment: It's difficult to diagnosis without any code snippet. Can please paste some ?

Comment: it would require having to rewrite the wrapper library, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: No I mean, just run a some test code, to prove that you can set the urlfetch timeout explicitly and it works.  Then you know it's what you are doing - which I sure is the case. But that gives you a confidence level.